# How can I reset the 'get info' preview image of archive utility?

Tags: archive

When I zip or download a zipped file, Archive Utility doesn't display it's default zip icon anymore. Also when viewing Info and the large Previewer icon.
It now displays this version of a program I seem to have installed (don't know which).

How can I turn it back to Archive Utility's default blue zip icon when I compress or download a zipped file?
I've tried everything from changing the Get Info icon to going to Core Services (where nothing has changed in the icns files or Archive Utility)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the default app to something else from the list of potential apps

[image]

Then click Change All..

[image]

Reboot.
Ensure the icon is now the correct one for your new choice, then repeat the process to revert to Archive Utility.

Comment: Didn't help. No matter what app I set it to and after restoring it to Archive Utility, that large zip image in the preview section stays the same.